# Why does Rx print whole array and not each item

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I have the following code:

```
 val places: Array<String> = arrayOf("Singapore", "Japan", "Norway") // From an Array - Output will be elements of the array
        val observable = Observable.fromArray(places)


        var result = "Hello, "

        observable.subscribe(
            { item ->
                result += item
            },
            { error ->
                error.printStackTrace()
            },
            {
                println("Done")
            }
        )

        print(result)
    }
```

I expect it to print Hello, Singapore | Hello, Japan | Hello, Norway

However I get:

```
Hello, [[Ljava.lang.String;@3830f1c0]
```

What am I missing in-order to print elements from the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Observable.fromArray`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#fromArray-T...-) is a bit different than, say, `fromIterable`. It doesn't take an actual array, but instead, it takes vararg arguments. Here's its signature:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> fromArray(T... items)
```

So calling it like this will actually give you an `Observable` containing a single element, and it will be of type `Observable<Array<String>>`:

```
val places: Array<String> = arrayOf("Singapore", "Japan", "Norway")
val observable: Observable<Array<String>> = Observable.fromArray(places)
```

What you're looking for, an `Observable<String>`, could be created like this:

```
val observable: Observable<String> = Observable.fromArray("Singapore", "Japan", "Norway")
```

Or, if you have an existing array, using the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

```
val places: Array<String> = arrayOf("Singapore", "Japan", "Norway")
val observable: Observable<String> = Observable.fromArray(*places)
```